# Окончание существительного в количественно-именном сочетании?

Tags: грамотная-речь, числительные, окончания, единственное-множественное-число, количественно-именное-сочетание

Как правильно: с 18 до 21 *часа* или *часов*?

Comment: Если вам дан хороший ответ, отметьте его галочкой.

Answer (score 1):

Правильно: с 18 часов до 21 часа.

Падежные изменения числительных (р. п.): восемнадцати, двадцати одного.

Краткая запись: с 18 до 21 час. (ед. изм. одна на оба числа), с 18:00 до 21:00.

Answer (score 1):

**С 18 часов** (Р. п., мн. ч.) **до 21 часа** (Р. п., ед. ч.).
Именно так пишут в  деловых и официальных текстах.

*Шаттлы будут возить поклонников футбола с 18 часов до 21 часа, а также с 23 часов до 1 часа ночи после окончания игры 1/8 финала Лиги Европы.*

В обиходной речи вполне допустима такая формулировка, когда существительное, согласованное с первым числительным, опускается:
**с 18 до 21 часа; с 18 до 21 минуты; с 18 до 21 рубля; с 18 до 21 животного.**

*По Нижнему Новгороду, Туле (...) существует вечерняя доставка заказов с 18 до 21 часа...*

Однако, в конструкциях, где основы ед. и мн. ч. супплетивны (т. е. их корневые морфы различны), необходимы оба существительных:
**с 18 лет до 21 года; с 18 детей до 21 ребенка.**

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, в разговоре можно пожертвовать строгой нормой ради краткости и сказать: "с 18 до 21 часа", но ни в коем случае не "с 18 до 21 часов".